# How do I read config values from application.yml in Spring 2.7.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've created a simple repo here that demonstrates my issue, just in case it helps anyone: https://github.com/kevinm416/spring-boot-config. I've tried various iterations of different Spring annotations I saw on different tutorials, but so far nothing has worked.

I have a very standard spring boot application:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({BaseConfig.class, FeedsConfig.class})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And a configuration class:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "feeds")
public class FeedsConfig {
    public List<String> urls;
    public String abc;
}
```

I've tried both `application.properties` and `application.yml` individually and at the same time, with contents like:

```yaml
feeds:
  abc: def
  urls:
    - url1
    - url2
    - url3
base: level
```

When I `@Autowire` the config class into a controller, the values from the application config are not populated.

```java
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private FeedsConfig feedsConfig;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    private String hello() {
        return "Hi " + feedsConfig.abc + ", " + feedsConfig.urls;
    }
}
```

I can see the values I want in the Environment under `propertySources` though! Why aren't my config classes being filled out?

[image: Debugger showing environment]

---

I changed FeedsConfig to this and it's working! Thank you Nicholas!

```java
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "feeds")
public class FeedsConfig {
    public FeedsConfig(List<String> urls, String abc) {
        this.urls = urls;
        this.abc = abc;
    }
    public List<String> urls;
    public String abc;
}
```

Comment: Your fields are just `public` while they should have a getter/setter as the setting is done using reflection and it is assumed the Java Beans convention is followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the components are properly scanned, I see two issues:

- `FeedsConfig` should not be annotated with `@Component`
- `FeedsConfig` should have a full-args constructor and be annotated with `@ConstructorBinding` to wire the properties

This can be easily achieved using Lombok (I use the same set-up on my machine):

```java
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "feeds")
@ConstructorBinding
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FeedsConfig {

    public List<String> urls;
    public String abc;
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to constructor binding. Using getters/setters will work the same. IMHO the main culprit should have been the `@Component`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your configuration properties class is missing `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` annotation. Also `@Component` and `@EnableConfigurationProperties` is no longer needed. Check out this tutorial, paragraph 3.1 https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "feeds")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class FeedsConfig {
    public List<String> urls;
    public String abc;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` to `FeedsConfig`, but that didn't change anything. When I remove `@EnableConfigurationProperties` from `Application`, I get this error: ```Field feedsConfig in com.config.test.HelloController required a bean of type 'com.config.test.FeedsConfig' that could not be found.```

Comment: This solution also requires `@EnableConfigurationProperties` and `@Component` annotation to be removed. Did you do so?